# Cost-Effective Alternatives to Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure-table-storage, nosql

I've recently been using Azure Table Storage for a use case that involves storing hundreds of gigabytes of relational/table data.  The table is regularly being queried to return datasets of ~100K entries.  A wait time of 15+ seconds is unacceptable (ideally, it would be < 5 seconds).   I have identified the 2000 entity/partition per second throughput limit as the limiting factor in my project.  Are there any low-cost NoSQL table storage alternatives that are preferably:

- Low-cost for storage
- Low-cost for queries (without being charged for each individual "entry" pulled from the store...batch queries?)
- Without VMs
- Most importantly, **high-throughput (greater than ATS)** and **low latency (like ATS)**

Comment: Is that possible to store your data in multiple Azure Storage tables, and query them simultaneously?

Comment: What's the difference between querying multiple tables simultaneously vs querying multiple partitions simultaneously?

Comment: The throttling is per partition. This is because each partition is stored on a single partition server, and Azure's SLA guarantees minimal performance. To increase throughput, use a different partitioning strategy if possible. I'm posting this as a comment because it does not answer Hugh's question as asked.

Comment: @Hugh, you can also query multiple partitions simultaneously. If your query returning 100K entities is across multiple partition key, you can split your query into multiple and do them simultaneously.

Comment: @ZhaoxingLu-Microsoft that's what I'm doing with a Parallel.ForEach loop.  Nevertheless, each partition is returning ~20k entries.  Perhaps a new partitioning scheme is in order.